Package "rgdal" cannot be found in R-v4.4
So i had to upgrade my R version to 4.4 to install a package called "INLA". This is in ubuntu machine btw. In addition to INLA, I also need to use the rgdal package. However when I tried to install it I get the following error. Any ideas on how I can fix this ?
Note I have installed GDAL using ubuntu.
sudo apt install libpq-dev gdal-bin libgdal-dev
And seems to work fine in python, from osgeo import gdal
install.packages("rgdal")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rgdal’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages


The package has been removed from CRAN: "Archived on 2023-10-16 at the request of the maintainer. Consider using 'sf' or 'terra' instead."
